# How to force reload of current page from browser cache

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

In javascript is there a way to reload the current page **from the browser cache** when the current URL includes a *fragment* (`#`)?

I know that `window.location.reload(false)` should do that, but I've tried and it doesn't, it still makes a request to the server.

If I do `window.location.href=window.location.href` it will load the HTML from the cache, but only when the URL does not include a *fragment*.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Your question brings forth my question, why would you want to do this? Is it to restore the screen in its original state / discard any changes made so far?

Comment: No, to reload a commercial banner which is generated by a javascript (that I can't change) on page load using `document.write` statements. So yes, the HTML is the same, but JS needs to re-execute in order to generate a different banner.

Comment: could you "fire" the `window.onload` function?

Comment: I could, but the document.writes would destroy the page. If you do a document write after the document has closed it will start a new document.

Comment: i am still at a loss why you cannot change the generation method for the banner. Nothing stops you to overwrite any generated elements (if you anyhow can change the html?) It rather seems like you would like to have a workaround for a bad design (no offense meant)

Comment: It IS bad design, but I can't change that. The banners come from an external system and must be injected on specific points in the HTML using some inline js call. The call then writes the banners into the document using document.write. That's why I can't reload them using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simplifiyng things but generally your browser will make the request regardless of cache state, it's server response that make browser use cache.

If server decides (based on request haders like: ETag or Cache headers) that cached version should be used and respond with `304 Not modified` browser will use cache version.

You may try to use [HTML5 cache manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5) (for browsers that support it) to avoid requests to the server for pages that doesn't changed without making requests to the page itself (but browser will still load manifest file)

Comment: I'm not sure that's true for modern browsers. I think they do use the HTML from the local cache without querying the server first. A 304 to my knowledge is a response to a browser revalidating its cached entry which it only does when the entry has gone stale.